# pyqt QtGraphicsView does not get updated within loop

Tags: python, pyqt

i have a GUI program built on PyQt, the GUI has a QtGraphicsView widget, which has a GraphicsScene, which has a Pixmap item to be displayed and updated, for instance, I use the following line to do this

```
view.scene().items().setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimage))
```

Everytime, i modify the qimage and call this line to update the image display, and it worked well.
later i want to add a loop to update the image continuously:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    qimage = .... #make some changes to qimage
    view.scene().items().setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimage))
```

well,the image does not get updated within the loop. the viewport only display the first image(i=0) and the last image(i = 9), i thought it was because the ViewportUpate option of the GraphicsView widget, but it still does not work after i use:`setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView.FullViewportUpdate)`...
Any idea?
Really thanks for the help!

Comment: its probably because it sends a notify event that something changed...however it does not have a chance to handle the update event since you are in a loop ... maybe look at using a timer class to call the code instead of a loop ...

Comment: maybe try adding `view.scene().update()`

Comment: @JoranBeasley i tried to add `time.sleep(1)` after setPixmap, but still no update, i also tried to add `view.scene().update()`, but still no update...

Answer (score 5):

Well, i think i found the issue
i have to add one more line`QApplication.processEvents()` to the loop
otherwise the loop will occupy the processing time and gives the program no chance to update

```
for i in xrange(10):
    qimage = .... #make some changes to qimage
    view.scene().items().setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimage))  
    QApplication.processEvents()
```

now it works. 
anyway, thanks to all!